# shinydashboard valueBox giving Error: Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'. prior to input

Tags: shinydashboard

I'm creating an app that will calculate risk of a heart event. I developed the risk formula (model) based on clinical risk factors.

The % risk output appears in a valueBox. However, prior to selecting inputs, Error: Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'. appears in place of the box.

I cannot see the problem in my code. From other examples I've seen, I think a box should be appear.

I am using current versions of R and all packages.

Hoping someone can help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)


ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
                dashboardPage(
                  dashboardHeader(title = "Risk Calculator"),
                  dashboardSidebar(
                                      selectInput("bp", 
                                                  label = "High Blood Pressure", 
                                                  choices = list("",
                                                                 "No"="0",
                                                                 "Yes"="7"),
                                                  selected = NULL,
                                                  width = "100%"),
                                      selectInput("chol", 
                                                  label = "Cholesterol", 
                                                  choices = list("",
                                                                "Low"="0",
                                                                "Moderate"="2",
                                                                "High"="4"),
                                                  selected = NULL,
                                                  multiple = FALSE,
                                                  width = "100%"),
                                      selectInput("pain", 
                                                  label = "Chest Pain", 
                                                  choices = list("",
                                                                 "No"="0",
                                                                 "Yes"="2"),
                                                  selected = NULL,
                                                  width = "100%"),
                                      selectInput("fam", 
                                                  label = "Family History of Heart Disease", 
                                                  choices = list("",
                                                                 "No"="0",
                                                                 "Yes"="4"),
                                                  selected = NULL,
                                                  width = "100%"),
                                     
                                      
                                      actionButton("submitbutton", 
                                                   "Calculate", 
                                                   class = "btn btn-primary")
                                    ),
                                    
                  dashboardBody(
                      fluidRow(
                        box(
                          title = "Risk Score:",
                          background = "light-blue",
                          width = 4,
                          textOutput("info")
                        )),
                      fluidRow(
                      valueBoxOutput("score"), width=6)
                )))
                      
                                
 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$score <- renderValueBox({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) {
      percent<- 100*(1/(1+(exp(10-0.8*(as.numeric(input$bp)+as.numeric(input$chol)+as.numeric(input$pain)+as.numeric(input$fam))))))
      riskcol<- cut(percent, breaks=c(0, 15, 40, 100), labels=c("green","orange","red"), right = FALSE)
      risktxt<- cut(percent, breaks=c(0, 15, 40, 100), labels=c("Low Risk","Moderate Risk","High Risk"), right = FALSE)
      valueBox(paste0((round(percent,digits=2)),"%"), risktxt, icon = icon("heart"), color = riskcol)
    } 
    
  })
  output$info <- renderText ({ "Estimated % Risk"  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```